# Android RealViewSwitcher : How to start on second page?

Tags: android, swipe, viewswitcher

i'm using RealViewSwitcher I got from [this site.](http://marcreichelt.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html)

It works perfectly on my code, but I don't have any idea **how to set the initial current screen** to second or third screen.

the method `setCurrentScreen(int)` doesn't affect anything and if I change the for loop inside the onLayout() method from `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {...}` into `for (int i = 1; i < count; i++){...}` It does starts in page two, but you can't go to page one.

Any idea how to start on page two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local solution is to add new class method. If you want start on second page - just call snapToScreenFast(2).

```
public void snapToScreenFast(int whichScreen) {
    if (!mScroller.isFinished())
        return;

    whichScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(whichScreen, getChildCount() - 1));

    mNextScreen = whichScreen;

    final int newX = whichScreen * getWidth();
    final int delta = newX - getScrollX();
    mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, 0);
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already found the answer months ago but forgot to update my question. Thanks